# How to set JAVA properties in Tomcat 9?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

How do I set Java properties in Tomcat 9? I believe that I used to be able to use tomcat.conf to set and load properties? Is this still the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Java properties in Tomcat 9 by adding them to the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.
For example, to set the `java.util.logging.config.file` property, you can add the following line to `bin/setenv.sh` (or `bin/setenv.bat` on Windows):

```bash
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties"
```